# What is the use of implicitIncludes property in Proxy reader

Tags: javascript, proxy

reader: {
            type: 'json',
            rootProperty: 'data.items',
            implicitIncludes: false
        }

Comment: What framework are you using? Where from is that code?

Answer (score 0):

`implicitIncludes` property in `reader` config is used to automatically parse response object and fill data in respected nested models.

Like : IF you have `user` model and another is `project` model. now one user can have multiple `project` so you can specify `hasMany` property in `user` model, after specifying that property, through one JSON(response) you can fill data in both `user` as well as in `project` model.

For more information please refer this [link](http://docs.sencha.com/extjs/6.2.0/classic/Ext.data.reader.Reader.html#cfg-implicitIncludes)